# adb logcat, only display custom log events?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, adb, android-logcat

I'm using `adb logcat -s Unity` to view log output from my Android build.  However, I'm getting lots of stuff that I don't always need:

```
08-10 15:53:25.956 17278 17297 D Unity   : Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.002394 / 0.00s ; BMI160 accelerometer / Bosch
08-10 15:53:25.960 17278 17297 D Unity   : Choreographer available: Enabling VSYNC timing
08-10 15:53:26.133 17278 17297 I Unity   : Launching UI...
08-10 15:53:26.133 17278 17297 I Unity   : UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
08-10 15:53:26.133 17278 17297 I Unity   : UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
08-10 15:53:26.133 17278 17297 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
08-10 15:53:26.133 17278 17297 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
```

Is there a way to only get messages I intentionally output, ie "Launching UI..." above?

Currently I'm using `Debug.Log()` to output these messages.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html#filteringOutput or just piping output through grep

Comment: I tried `adb logcat Unity:I` but it still showed events with E and D.  Even so, many of the examples I want filtered above are the same category as the one line I don't want filtered (I).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can prefix every log message you send.

```
Debug.Log("<my-prefix> Hello World");
```

And then, on linux:

```
adb logcat | grep '<my-prefix>'
```

Or on Windows:

```
adb logcat | find "<my-prefix>"
```

You can also make your own log method to automatically prefix your log message.

**EDIT**

Using the -e option of logcat you can get the same behavior:

```
adb logcat -e <my-prefix>
```

Comment: I think on Windows double quotation mark should be used on the parameter of find. (i.e. `adb logcat | find "<my-prefix>"`)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following command to get debug log of unity project,

```
adb logcat -s Unity PackageManager dalvikvm DEBUG
```